# Call Command from Mupen64Plus dll using RUNDLL32 through Command Prompt

Tags: dll, cmd, emulation, command-prompt

I'm using the Nintendo 64 emulator, [Mupen64Plus](https://mupen64plus.org/).

It has a file called `mupen64plus-ui-console.exe` used to launch games through command-line. It also accepts keyboard shortcuts to perform commands, but it is limited.

---

**Mupen64Plus Commands/Functions**

[This wiki page](https://mupen64plus.org/wiki/index.php?title=Mupen64Plus_v2.0_Core_Front-End) shows a list of all commands that can be called, I think from the `mupen64plus.dll`.

---

**RUNDLL32**

I read how to pass commands to a dll like this:

```
RUNDLL32.EXE <dllname>,<entrypoint> <optional arguments>
```

---

**Calling a Command with RUNDLL32**

I'm trying to call `M64CMD_STATE_LOAD` with `cmd.exe`, to load a save file.

Info from Wiki:

> Command Functions Prototype   m64p_error CoreDoCommand(m64p_command
>   Command, int ParamInt, void *ParamPtr)
>
> ParamInt Ignored ParamPtr Pointer to string containing state file path
>   and name, or NULL
>
> This command will attempt to load a saved state file. If ParamPtr is
>   not NULL, this function will load a state file from a full pathname
>   specified by this pointer. Otherwise (ParamPtr is NULL), it will load
>   from the current slot.

I have the Mupen64Plus emulator running a game. I then open `cmd.exe` and paste in this line.

```
RUNDLL32.EXE "C:\Path\To\mupen64plus.dll", CoreDoCommand M64CMD_STATE_LOAD 1 "C:\Path\To\MySave.m64p"
```

---

**Problem**

It accepts the command, I get no errors, but the save file isn't loaded.

---

**Questions**

1. Are the arguments being passed wrong?
2. Does the `mupen64plus.dll` not have hooks into the currently running `mupen64plus-ui-console.exe`?
3. Is it loading the save file into nothing?
4. Is it not possible to do it this way?

Comment: Not sure, but aren't spaces around the `,` problematic?

Comment: @aschipfl I'm not sure, it gives the same result with or without. I think the `mupen64plus-ui-console.exe` launches the game with the `CoreStartup()` dll command and creates some kind of hooks into it. And when I try to use a separate cmd window to talk to the dll, the new instance doesn't see the game running.